# Java unit test cannot access resource from application project

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, maven, resources

The unit tests are located in a different project than the actual application. If I run a method which references a resource, I do not find it from within the test. If I run the same method in the application, everything works fine. So far I tried these two approaches to get an URL to the resource:

```
new URL("platform:/plugin/application/res/its_name.xml")
```

and

```
this.getClass().getResource("/its_name.xml");
```

Is there any simple way (in eclipse) to make the resource accessible to the test project, or do I need to put the test into the same project as the application?

The folder structure is like this:

```
application
           \src
               \packages
           \res

tests
     \src
```

Comment: Why isn't your test in the same project?

Comment: In what folder are these resources? Can you share with us your project's skeleton?

Comment: My test is not in the same project, because I received it like this.

Comment: you can try by adding your dependent project in test projects build path. In `Build Path` click `Configure build path` --> select `Projects tab` --> click `add` and select your `required project`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build your project in a JAR file and add it to the test project... but I really don't recommend that you separate your project from the junit tests because it will only make things harder for you.

Comment: If the test project is executed inside eclipse the dependency jar is not required. The required project can be included in the test project's build path.

Comment: yeah that would also work... but I was just trying to give a general solution... anyway I think he/she should write the tests inside the project in a separate source folder... that would be a lot easier and there is no gain from writing in a separate project anyway...